# ptrace - Input/Output Error (errno 5) on 32 bits only

Tags: c++, linux, code-injection, errno, ptrace

I was trying to inject a shared library in another process and I managed to get it working on x64. Though, when I tried using it for 32bits, something weird is happening: ptrace is not being able to execute properly due to an Input/Output error (errno 5). I don't know what to do, since this same code worked for x64.
Then, I tried to make a smaller example using a function that I called `test_ptrace`. Surprisingly, the error doesn't happen there, though it is doing essentially the same thing (allocate memory on target process, inject a payload, set registers to match the payload, run the payload). When I saw the error was not happening, I tried again injecting the shared library with ptrace using a function called `load_library`. But unfortunately, there the error was again.

```cpp
//this is the function that is NOT working, 'load_library'
void* load_library(pid_t pid, std::string path, int mode)
{
    int status;
    struct user_regs_struct old_regs, regs;
    void* dlopen_ex = (void*)0xf7c29700; //I disabled ASLR, so this address does not change
    void* handle_ex = (void*)-1;

    unsigned char inj_buf[] =
    {
        0x51,       //push ecx
        0x53,       //push ebx
        0xFF, 0xD0, //call eax
        0xCC,       //int3 (SIGTRAP)
    };

    size_t path_size = path.size();
    size_t inj_size  = sizeof(inj_buf) + path_size;
    void*  inj_addr  = allocate_memory(pid, inj_size, PROT_EXEC | PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE);
    void*  path_addr = (void*)((uintptr_t)inj_addr + sizeof(inj_buf));
    write_memory(pid, inj_addr, (void*)inj_buf, sizeof(inj_buf));
    write_memory(pid, path_addr, (void*)path.c_str(), path_size);

    if(ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL))
    {
        perror("PTRACE_ATTACH");
        std::cout << "Errno: " << errno << std::endl;
        return handle_ex;
    }
    wait(&status);
    if(ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, NULL, &old_regs) == -1)
    {
        perror("PTRACE_GETREGS");
        std::cout << "Errno: " << errno << std::endl;
        return handle_ex;
    }

    regs.eax = (unsigned long)dlopen_ex;
    regs.ebx = (unsigned long)path_addr;
    regs.ecx = (unsigned long)mode;
    regs.eip = (unsigned long)inj_addr;

    if(ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, NULL, &regs) == -1)
    {
        perror("PTRACE_SETREGS");
        std::cout << "Errno: " << errno << std::endl;
        return handle_ex;
    }
    
    if(ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, NULL, NULL) == -1)
    {
        perror("PTRACE_CONT");
        std::cout << "Errno: " << errno << std::endl;
        return handle_ex;
    }

    waitpid(pid, &status, WSTOPPED);
    if(ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, NULL, &regs) == -1)
    {
        perror("PTRACE_GETREGS");
        std::cout << "Errno: " << errno << std::endl;
        return handle_ex;
    }

    handle_ex = (void*)old_regs.eax;

    if(ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, NULL, &old_regs) == -1)
    {
        perror("PTRACE_SETREGS");
        std::cout << "Errno: " << errno << std::endl;
        return handle_ex;
    }

    if(ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, NULL) == -1)
    {
        perror("PTRACE_DETACH");
        std::cout << "Errno: " << errno << std::endl;
        return handle_ex;
    }

    deallocate_memory(pid, inj_addr, inj_size);

    return handle_ex;
}
```

```cpp
//this one, though, is working, but it is very similar to the function 
//above (except it doesn't restore the execution, but the code of the 
//other function doesn't even get there anyway.
void test_ptrace(pid_t pid)
{
    int status;
    struct user_regs_struct regs;
    unsigned char inj_buf[] =
    {
        0xCD, 0x80,               //int80 (syscall)
        0xCC,                     //int3  (SIGTRAP)
    };

    void* inj_addr = allocate_memory(pid, sizeof(inj_buf), PROT_EXEC | PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE);
    write_memory(pid, inj_addr, inj_buf, sizeof(inj_buf));

    std::cout << "--ptrace test started--" << std::endl;

    if(ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL) == -1)
    {
        perror("PTRACE_ATTACH");
        std::cout << "Errno: " << errno << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    wait(&status);

    if(ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, NULL, &regs) == -1)
    {
        perror("PTRACE_GETREGS");
        std::cout << "Errno: " << errno << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    regs.eax = __NR_exit;
    regs.ebx = 222;
    regs.eip = (unsigned long)inj_addr;

    if(ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, NULL, &regs) == -1)
    {
        perror("PTRACE_SETREGS");
        std::cout << "Errno: " << errno << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    if(ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, NULL) == -1)
    {
        perror("PTRACE_DETACH");
        std::cout << "Errno: " << errno << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    std::cout << "--ptrace test ended--" << std::endl;
}
```

Program entry:

```
int main()
{
    pid_t pid = get_process_id("target");
    std::cout << "PID: " << pid << std::endl;
    std::string lib_path = "<my_path>/ptrace-test/libtest.so";
    load_library(pid, lib_path, RTLD_LAZY);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
PID: 2383
PTRACE_SETREGS: Input/output error
Errno: 5
```

If you need the whole project as a 'minimal' reproducible example, here you go: https://github.com/rdbo/ptrace-test

The PID is correct, I'm running as root, both the tracer and the tracee are compiled with G++ on 32 bits. Running up-to-date Manjaro. Any ideas?

Comment: the problem is in `allocate_memory`. x64 and x86 has different memory layout in protect mode. if the `inj_addr` is invalid, it will fail ....

Comment: I don't understand though, allocate_memory runs without any issue and returns a valid address. The problem happens in PTRACE_SETREGS, but how is it related to the previously alocated address?

Comment: `allocate_memory ` can return any address (which you hide this function and i assume it can point to any address to the target process); and you cannot guarantee it is point to a safe one. if it points to for example a system zone, you definitely will get error ...

Comment: You can check the code of `allocate_memory` in the GitHub repository. It injects a __NR_mmap (or __NR_mmap2 for 32 bits) syscall in the target process and then retrieves the return value from EAX/RAX. I checked how that address looked in memory and it does show "rwxp", so I think it's something else. Also, `allocate_memory` is being used on the function `test_ptrace`, which is working.

Comment: I just found something weird, it seems to be getting the Input/Output error on x64 too, but it still injects the registers somehow. This just gets more confusing

Comment: No way, I'm building them with a Makefile (you can see them in the github repository on the end of the post). The architecture is defined on the top and used to compile the target/tracee and the tracer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. Don't ask me how, though, I have no clue. I followed the exact same logic and out of sudden it worked. I used the working `test_ptrace` and kept putting the `load_library` code on it line by line to see what could be causing the problem. Turns out, I got it fixed and still don't know what it was. Anyways, here's the code (it is a bit messed up, because I didn't expect it to work):

```
void load_library(pid_t pid, std::string lib_path)
{
    int status;
    struct user_regs_struct old_regs, regs;
    unsigned char inj_buf[] =
    {
        0x51,       //push ecx
        0x53,       //push ebx
        0xFF, 0xD0, //call eax
        0xCC,       //int3 (SIGTRAP)
    };

    size_t inj_size = sizeof(inj_buf) + lib_path.size();
    void* inj_addr = allocate_memory(pid, inj_size, PROT_EXEC | PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE);
    void* path_addr = (void*)((uintptr_t)inj_addr + sizeof(inj_buf));
    write_memory(pid, inj_addr, inj_buf, sizeof(inj_buf));
    write_memory(pid, path_addr, (void*)lib_path.c_str(), lib_path.size());

    std::cout << "--ptrace test started--" << std::endl;

    if(ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL) == -1)
    {
        perror("PTRACE_ATTACH");
        std::cout << "Errno: " << errno << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    wait(&status);

    if(ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, NULL, &old_regs) == -1)
    {
        perror("PTRACE_GETREGS");
        std::cout << "Errno: " << errno << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    regs = old_regs;

    long dlopen_ex = 0xf7c28700;

    regs.eax = dlopen_ex;
    regs.ebx = (long)path_addr;
    regs.ecx = RTLD_LAZY;
    regs.eip = (unsigned long)inj_addr;

    if(ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, NULL, &regs) == -1)
    {
        perror("PTRACE_SETREGS");
        std::cout << "Errno: " << errno << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, NULL, NULL);
    waitpid(pid, &status, WSTOPPED);
    ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, NULL, &old_regs);

    if(ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, NULL) == -1)
    {
        perror("PTRACE_DETACH");
        std::cout << "Errno: " << errno << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    deallocate_memory(pid, inj_addr, inj_size);

    std::cout << "--ptrace test ended--" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
PID: 24615
--ptrace test started--
--ptrace test ended--
```

Target Process:

```
PID: 24615
dlopen: 0xf7c28700
Waiting...
Injected!
Waiting...
Waiting...
Waiting...
Waiting...
```

EDIT:
I just remembered I ran the following command as root (could've been it, not sure though):
`echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`
EDIT2: It was not it, the code is still working after a reboot. Also, I improved the code a bit on the GitHub repository.